# PyInstaller to create executable program that will pull a existing .xlsx file and read it

Tags: python, pyinstaller, xlsx

I've been trying to find a solution to this problem for a long time now. So from what I understand when you `pyinstaller --add-data 'file.xlsx:.'` it will create the file.xlsx in the temporary folder and when the program runs it will pull the xlsx file from that temp folder. So if I edit the xlsx file when I run the executable it will not pull the new data from the xlsx file. It will use the old one that was created when I compiled the program.

I could be wrong so correct me if I am. I'm very sorry if this question is in a confusing format this is the first question I have asked. Please ask me if you want any more details on what I'm trying to do. This would be extremely helpful if someone could help me figure this out. Thank you!

Comment: Also im using pandas to read the xlsx file

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be helpful if you explained to us what exactly you are trying to achieve, and what platform you are using. Because if you just want your Python script to load an Excel file from disk you do not need pyinstaller for that

Comment: Yes you’re right - files that are bundled into the exe will be extracted to the temporary folder where the exe is extracted to - yes your code and read them, and could update them there, but the hint is in the ‘temporary’’ - this will be deleted once the program exits. Next time your exe is run it extracts its content to a probably different temporary location and the files as bundled into the exe are extracted there - so as you suspect your code which is reading files from the new/different temporary folder will get the original data bundled into the exe.

Comment: If you want files to persist with a longer lifetime than your program then these files _can’t_ be bundled into the exe - except perhaps you could bundle your xlsx in as a starter content that you copy somewhere outside the temporary folder to become the persistent file. This could be in the same folder as the .exe file itself, or somewhere you can configure like a home folder - basically, anywhere not in the temporary folder the exe (and any bundled data files) is extracted to when running.

Comment: Yes I am looking for something where I can pull the xlsx file from outside the temporary folder. Im not exactly sure how I would do something like this. I am using PyIntaller to compile my program because I need this to run on computers that do not have have python and pandas installed. So would there be a way to pull these files directly from the same directory my exe file is in. If this is possible I would greatly appreciate you helping me figure this out, thank you.

Comment: I am also aware that if this is going to be run on other computers the file path will change. I will worry about that part. I just need to be able to pull it from my personal computer first.